# When is an index (in a DBMS) a bad index?

Tags: sql, indexing

Can anyone tell me when an index is a bad index?

Comment: You might want to reelaborate your question (and its title). Maybe you mean "SQL Table bad indexing" - "What parameters should I take in count to define an index as a bad index and replace it?"

Comment: Once upon a time there was a index. But this was not an ordinary index. It looked normal, but it was a bad index. When noone noticed, it got unbalanced with leaf nodes hanging off leaf nodes in a complete mess. Not only did it have too many leaf nodes, it was also hanging out with a gang of bad statistics. Then one day, a fairy called DBCC came by and said to the index "why are you a bad index? shouldn't you be a good index like all the other indexes"? She waved her magic wand and reindexes. After that, she updated statistics to make the bad statistics go away. The index said to the fairy "...

Comment: Interesting side-light: the SQL standard says nothing whatsoever about indexes.  The CREATE INDEX statement is not standardized.

Answer (score 11):

If the indexed column is never searched on and the table is heavily updated you don't get the benefit of performance that indeces are for. In contrary you might suffer performance hit.

Answer (score 11):

One circumstance under which an index is pretty much unconditionally bad is if there is another index which uses the same columns (in the *same* order) as a prefix:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_good ON SomeTable(Col1, Col2, Col3);
CREATE INDEX ix_bad  ON SomeTable(Col1, Col2);
```

The bad index is a waste of disk space and slows down modify operations to no benefit.

Answer (score 9):

I've linked to it before, and I'll link to it again, because it's excellent:

[SQL Indexing in 9 Minutes and a Half, by Stephane Faroult.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZgG7ttJTSc)

Answer (score 6):

One important thing to keep in mind with indexes (apart from the aforementioned "actual-use" part) is the notion of selectivity.

When constructing indexes, you want to create indexes on columns that have a good chance of "high selectivity".  This requires some understanding of the data in the column (which you may or may not have depending on your knowledge of the domain / availability of sample data).

Selectivity = # of Distinct Values / Total # of Rows

Lets use a table "People" with columns for Given_name, Surname, Gender, Age

For example, creating an index on a column such as Gender (where gender is constrained to NULL, M or F) would not provide much benefit during a query (especially if the query already results in a table scan for other reasons).  In any scenario, the selectivity of this index would be extremely low.  Depending on the DBMS, using this index may actually be worse that a full table scan.

However, creating a composite index on ( Given_name , Surname ) would provide benefits when executing queries against those columns.  The selectivity of this index (for most populations) would be pretty good.

An index with selectivity of 1 is the ideal, however, the only way to achieve a selectivity of 1 is to have a unique index on a non-nullable column.

Also, keep in mind that you can easily write queries to "keep track" of your indexes and their selectivity.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is never used, it is a bad index (if you feel unecessary things are bad.).

Comment: Thank you  very much...but how can you say an created index is not using

Comment: Example: you have a field called: Other_Comments. No one has ever entered any data in the field. No one has ever queried the field. What would be the point of an index on this field? It is just going to slow down any insert, delete or update activity.

Answer (score 1):

The index is to help us to search the rows faster.

If the index column is *not used for searches* there is no point in defining it.

If the values in that column ***keep changing*** very frequently it will be extra work for database server (for re-indexing)

If there are ***too many inserts and deletes*** from table it will be extra work for server

Comment: Don't forget that indexes can be on sets of columns.

Comment: Thank you  very much...but how can we say an indexed column is not used frequently

Comment: @Johathan thanks for the fact.

@venkat if you are not using the indexed column(s) in join or where clause for selecting rows from the table it is less frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inherent performance hit from having indexes (creation and maintenance of the structure). You usually want that hit to get the benefit of faster scans. When you don't get the benefit it's just a net loss and that's a bad index.

Possible reasons:

- Never used indexes
- Redundant indexes
- Tables that aren't scanned very often but updated continuously (the hit of having the index outgrows the benefits, because the table is rarely scanned).
- Tables that are scanned often and updated continuously. In this case you can get both the benefit of an index and a snappy update/insert by having an indexless table for inserts/updates and a table with indexes for the scans that gets updated in daily or hourly batches (there are cases where this doesn't work, of course. Then you need to get better hardware or redesign the app if you get a serious performance problem in such a case).

How to find your bad indexes? Most RDBMSs have options to show the query plan, there you can see if the indexes you set up are being used in the way you expect them to. This leads me to a final advice, think about your indexes, never create one "just in case".

Answer (score 1):

An index is bad if you never search on it. For example, an index (Col1, Col2, Col3) is a waste of resources if you never search with Col1, Col2 and Col3 in the same query.